# Where is Instruments iOS AutoLayout Tool in Xcode 10?

Tags: ios, autolayout, instruments

[At WWDC Apple promised to release a new Instruments tool for debugging AutoLayout on iOS. It should be released "later".](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/220/?time=1683) I couldn't find it in the Xcode 10.0.0 release version. Did I overlook something, or didn't Apple release it yet?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Instruments tool that they are talking about in the video has not been released yet (as of Xcode 11 beta 5).

---

However, there is already an older Instruments tool which might help you debug Auto Layout on iOS. I tested the tool on an iPhone simulator in Xcode 10.2 and that works. However, I am not sure if it works on an actual device.

Here's how to access it:

1. Create a new Standard > Blank template.
2. Click on the `+` button > search for the `Cocoa Layout` template.
3. Once you have the `Cocoa Layout` template, it is possible to save it as a custom template so that you can access it directly from Custom > Your Template next time.

There is an old but nice tutorial for this tool [here](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/inspecting-auto-layout-with-the-cocoa-layout-instrument/).

Answer (score 4):

You did not overlook anything! Apple did not release it Yet (Xcode Version 10.2 (10E125)).

You can find new release note of Xcode 10 [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_release_notes), in release notes you can see there is no news about addition of AutoLayout tool.

Answer (score 0):

Apple released an instrument for SwiftUI in Xcode 11. Seems like they dropped the plan to release one for regular autolayout and instead concentrated on providing a better experience for SwiftUI.

Here is an [article about the instrument](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-use-instruments-to-profile-your-swiftui-code-and-identify-slow-layouts).